# errors when opening file - it is opening as read only

Tags: vba, excel

Having a few issues when opening an external excel file.

Basically we have a system where we use a template excel file that writes to another excel workbook. (Multiple users could be in a template file at any one time)

The code is pretty straight forward in that it opens the file as readonly when extracting information and it opens the file as normal when adding/updating new information.

An issue has arose though with 1 particular user - when they click the button to update it always opens the file as read only (doesn't happen to anyone else) I have tried putting her on a different PC and it worked fine - so I am thinking it must be something to do with her settings on our system.

As anyone else come across this or any ideas how to resolve? (Done a office repair but didn't help)

Thanks

Comment: This normally happens with excel. You have to kill the process in task manager before using the sheet in your PC

Comment: 1. Make sure the file is not set to read only (right click -> properties -> uncheck read only). 2. Reboot the machine, don't take the user's word for it that they've done it - watch the machine reboot yourself ;)